# Obtaining a SAML token from a security token service on windows xp - without using WIF

Tags: .net, azure, saml-2.0, federated-identity, ws-trust

I am trying to obtain a SAML token for my user on a WPF client application that needs to run on Windows-XP and above. I get the SAML from my identity provider using WS-Trust and I pass it onto the Azure Access Control Service which returns me a Simple Web Token using O-Auth that I use to authenticate the user on the client and make calls to a secure API on Azure that trusts the ACS.

My code uses WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) and works fine operating systems above windows-xp. The only examples that I have seen of this use WIF to request the SAML tokens from a security token service but WIF is not supported on windows-xp as a result of which I am stuck. I tried to do some research but could not find a way of accomplishing the above stated scenario without using WIF. Is there any way for me to do this on a windows xp client? If not then what should I be doing differently?

The code that I use to get tokens is:

//GetSamlToken from STS for ACS realm using UserCredential, this uses WIF

```
    private SecurityToken GetSamlToken(string realm, string stsEndpoint, UserCredential userCredential)
    {
        Logger.Info("Getting Saml Token from Identity provider...");

        using (var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential), new EndpointAddress(new Uri(stsEndpoint))))
        {
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userCredential.UserName;
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = userCredential.Password;
            factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

            WSTrustChannel channel = null;

            try
            {
                var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
                    {
                        RequestType = WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
                        AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(realm),
                        KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
                    };

                channel = (WSTrustChannel)factory.CreateChannel();

                RequestSecurityTokenResponse response;
                var token = channel.Issue(rst, out response);

                Logger.Info("Got Saml Token from Identity provider.");

                return token;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (channel != null)
                {
                    channel.Abort();
                }

                factory.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

//Gets OAuthToken from an ACS serviceEndpoint using a xmlSamlToken obtained from a STS.

```
    private NameValueCollection GetOAuthToken(string xmlSamlToken, string serviceEndpoint, string acsRelyingParty)
    {
        Logger.Info("Passing Saml token to ACS...");
        WebClient client = new WebClient { BaseAddress = serviceEndpoint };

        var values = new NameValueCollection
                         {
                             { "grant_type", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" }, 
                             { "assertion", xmlSamlToken },
                             { "scope", acsRelyingParty }

                         };

        byte[] acsTokenResponse = client.UploadValues("v2/OAuth2-13", "POST", values);
        string acsToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(acsTokenResponse);
        var tokens = new NameValueCollection();
        var parsed = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(acsToken) as Dictionary<string, object>;
        Logger.Info("Parsed OAuth token.");

        foreach (var item in parsed)
        {
            tokens.Add(item.Key, item.Value.ToString());
        }

        Logger.Info("Returning OAuth token.");
        return tokens;
    }
```

Comment: I guess another way of asking this question is does anyone know how to request a SAML token from a WS-Trust endpoint (https://exampledomain.com/issue/wstrust/mixed/username) using SOAP in .net?